# jQuery replace span contains comma with single comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to replace `<span class="test">,</span>`  to `,` I have tried as

```
if($('.elq-form').hasClass('elq-form')) {
   $(".elq-form").html( $(".elq-form").html().replace(/<span class="test">,</span>/g,",") ); }
}
```

I'm getting

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags

how to replace the span tag with `comma(,)` ?

Comment: You shouldn't use regex for html: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8796313

Comment: what is this `if($('.elq-form').hasClass('elq-form')) {` :| if you select element by `.elq-form` class, so it has this class ~!

Answer (score 5):

Simply use `unwrap`

```js
$(".elq-form").find('span.test').contents().unwrap();
```

```css
.test {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elq-form">
  <span class="test">,</span>
  <a>Blah Blah</a>
  <span class="test">,</span>
  <p>Blah Blah</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You may want `.find("span.test")` since the OP's code was specific to spans. (Who knows, maybe they have other `.test` elements...)

Answer (score 1):

`/` has special meaning in RegEx, you have to escape (`\/`) that:

```
$(".elq-form").html( $(".elq-form").html().replace(/<span class="test">,<\/span>/g,",") );
```

Comment: True, but it's still a Bad Idea.™ :-) *(And surely there's a dupetarget, if this is the answer to the question...)*